# Flutter - Keyboard not showing up in android 12 devices

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard

Keyboard is not showing up for android 12 devices, overlay comes indicating keyboard is on but nothing is shown. It is working properly for older android versions.

Keyboard is working fine in other apps & also works fine with simulator having android version other than Android 12. Tried with physical device also Pixel with android 12 facing the same issue.

flutter doctor code -

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/uable/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (4 months ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/uable/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/uable/Library/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/uable/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4638.54

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Below is an image of simple text field with keyboard on have tried changing all properties of text field also. Its an existing application so tried testing the existing textfields even in those its showing the same behaviour.

android gradle settings

```
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 30
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sharan, did you fix this bug? I'm facing the same problem!

Comment: @Abdel yes in the android manifest file you have to set android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: I have the same problem, just tried adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" but it doesn't appear to have made a difference. In my case it is a Flutter webview not triggering the keyboard show.

Comment: Running into the exact same issues as @theLastNightTrain: the flag `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` is set properly and my webview doesn't show they keyboard... (only on android 12 though, on a physical device...)

Comment: So on a physical android 12 device, in a webview, what fixed it for me was to use `(Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();`. Basically, putting the webview in Hybrid composition mode (see https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

Comment: When I use hybrid composition with the webviews, I get this issue. Not sure what I'm doing that other people aren't to make it work. So with virtual I can't use the keyboard in android 12, and hybrid the app freezes. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86157

Comment: @DidierProphete solution did the trick for me. Bravo

Answer (score 1):

Go to android simulator --> tools --> AVD Manager--> Select the device you are running and `wipedata` and run it again.

If it not works select another device and try it.

Am not sure, it may the problem in `simulator`.

Comment: Keyboard is working fine in other apps & also works fine with simulator having android version other than Android 12. Tried with physical device Pixel also with android 12 facing the same issue.

Comment: @SharanSingh Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @SharanSingh got any update? am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I think this bug because this simulator error with system UI , u can wipe data of simulator then run again

Answer (score 0):

as official document of webview flutter
put

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
```

in your `Main.dart`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HIsm.png)